# HostListener incorrectly errors TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

I'm having problems with my Angular 10.x / TypeScript 4.0.3 project getting linting rules setup correctly. In my `tsconfig.json` file I've specified `noUnusedLocals` and `noUnusedParameters` as I'd like to catch any unused imports and variable creation. However I'm running into an issue with the following line:

```
@HostListener('window:resize')
private onResize() {
  this.updatePosition()
}
```

I end up with the following compiler error as `this.onResize` is never called within the class.

```
'onResize' is declared but its value is never read.
```

Is there a way I can get around this? I'm also using `eslint` with the following config (unrelated to this, but I can use the eslint checks instead if necessary, incase there's some sort of reccomended Angular configuration that I'm not aware of)

```
{
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "extends": [
      "plugin:prettier/recommended",
      "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2020,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off"
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `public`? Also to improve performance, use `@HostListener('window:resize', [])`

Comment: That worked! and good call outs too, thank you!